# Ubuntu asks to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 every 5 mins, how to stop that?

Tags: 13.10

I've clicked don't upgrade, I've clicked any possible button, but I still get that annoying modal box asking me to upgrade. How do I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Software & Updates" > "Updates" > "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" > Set it to "Never"

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps to stop that annoying message.

- Execute following command to open **Software Sources** in terminal

  ```
  sudo software-properties-gtk
  ```
- Go to <kbd>Updates</kbd> tab and uncheck all four checkboxes their. and select <kbd>Never</kbd> for `Automatically check for updates:` option.  <sub>Unchecking the checkboxes would be optional</sub>
- <kbd>Close</kbd> the window.
- Execute this command to update the repository:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- After that you'll not get any message. If you want to get again such message just follow the same procedure and do the opposite.

Hope this short description help you.. Reply if you need any further assistance..

Comment: But this will disable any notification of new updates for all of his software. If he just wants to get rid of the 13.10 update, but still want notifications on other software he should only uncheck the auto update for new Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @AsgerBjørnJørgensen I just realized after posting my answer, and Updated my answer.. Reply if still something missing.